# Can't disable a warning 4700 in c++ MSVS08

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, warnings

My problem is that I cant find how to disable warning 4700 (variable used without initialisation)...
My code is the next:

```
#pragma warning(disable :4700)
double** f;
optimumWindowSize(Mv[seed_coord.x][seed_coord.y],f,&winsize);
#pragma warning(default :4700)
```

Inside `optimumWindowSize` I call a function that initializes the variable f, so actually I am not using it without initialisation, but still the compiler gives me the warning. I only want to disable it here, not in all the code, but with my code above I don't disable it.

What I am missing?
How can I disable it?

NOTE: F will be a winsizeXwinsize matrix after the function

Comment: Are you SURE that's the right call for that? Should it not be `double *f;` and use `&f` in the call. Otherwise, adding `double** f = NULL;` isn't going to add more than one instruction, I'd expect. And hopefully this isn't done a gazilion times.

Comment: Are you initializing `f` of `*f` in the function? I'll bet that MSVC++ is correct, thta you have failed to initialize `f`, and therefore `optimumWindowSize` can't initialize `*f`

Comment: @MatsPetersson Nope! f will be a NxN matrix, rigth now i am just passing an adress and the function would give me the whole matrix and N (actually winsize).

Comment: So it is passed as a reference?

Comment: Yes, It is the variable where after the function I want to have the matrix stored

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer, Is is just needed to initialize the `f` variable with `NULL` and the warning is gone.